# LibreOffice Base - joint variable calculation using SQL

Tags: sql, libreoffice, radix

I have a table with 3 columns, for example, `Food`, `Type`, and `Taste`.

- Column `Food` can have anything
- Column `Type` may have 'Fruit' or 'Vegetable' as possible values
- Column `Taste` may have 'Bad', 'Good' or 'Delicious' as possible values

I am trying to get (with no luck so far) a SQL statement that would produce a table like:

```
            Bad       Good    Delicious   Total
Fruit        05         09           16      20
Vegetables   12         20           03      35
Total        17         29           19      55
```

Were the numbers on the output table are the COUNT of how many `Food` are in the table for each `Type` / `Taste` combination.

How can that be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first two lines can be done in one query with a subquery clause:

```
SELECT X."Type", 
       SUM(X."Bad") AS "Bad",
       SUM(X."Good") AS "Good",
       SUM(X."Delicious") AS "Delicious",
       SUM(X."Total") AS "Total" 
FROM (SELECT "Type",
          CASEWHEN("Taste" = 'Bad',1,0) AS "Bad",
          CASEWHEN("Taste" = 'Good',1,0) AS "Good",
          CASEWHEN("Taste" = 'Delicious',1,0) AS "Delicious",
          1 AS "Total" FROM "YourTableName") X 
GROUP BY "Type"
```

The subquery creates the columns "Bad", "Good" and "Delicious" with a 1 or 0 in each column, then the outer part of the query adds up all the values.

To get the totals row at the bottom, you have to use `UNION ALL` which is not supported by the Base parser.  For this query to work you will need to turn on the `Edit`→`Run SQL Directly` option.  (This will disable certain form and report functionality that requires the parser - it may not matter for your usage, but just FYI for if you later use this query in a form or report.)

The query you will `UNION ALL` with is basically the same query, you just don't group by the types.  So with the totals:

```
SELECT X."Type", 
       SUM(X."Bad") AS "Bad",
       SUM(X."Good") AS "Good",
       SUM(X."Delicious") AS "Delicious",
       SUM(X."Total") AS "Total" 
FROM (SELECT "Type",
          CASEWHEN("Taste" = 'Bad',1,0) AS "Bad",
          CASEWHEN("Taste" = 'Good',1,0) AS "Good",
          CASEWHEN("Taste" = 'Delicious',1,0) AS "Delicious",
          1 AS "Total" FROM "YourTableName") X 
GROUP BY "Type"

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Total' AS "BottomTotal",
       SUM(Y."Bad"),
       SUM(Y."Good"),
       SUM(Y."Delicious"),
       SUM(Y."Total") 
FROM (SELECT CASEWHEN("Taste" = 'Bad',1,0) AS "Bad",
          CASEWHEN("Taste" = 'Good',1,0) AS "Good",
          CASEWHEN("Taste" = 'Delicious',1,0) AS "Delicious",
          1 AS "Total" FROM "YourTableName") Y 
GROUP BY "BottomTotal"
```

Make sure to replace "YourTableName" with your actual table name throughout.